# Return href minus string

Tags: jquery, string, hash, replace

Now I got this piece of script that adds ?category to all links in an element. The problem is that I have a comment button that returns an url like this "http://example.com/post2#respond", which means that my script will return "http://example.com/post2#respond?category". And this is a problem because I'm using PHP for that query and everything behind # does not get parsed by to the server.

**This is the code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".comments-link a").attr("href", function(i, href) {  return href + "?category";   });
});
```

I'd like to do something like

```
return href.replace(/#respond/gi") + "?category" + "#respond"
```

so it'll end up http://example.com/post2?category#respond

Edit: I managed to remove 'respond' with href.replace, but not the hashtag

Comment: You may be want to hear about [url.js](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/).

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to avoid an external library for something simple like this.

Answer (score 0):

href.replace works. Just messed up the syntax.

```
$(".comments-link a").attr("href", function(i, href) {  return href.replace(/#respond/gi, '') + "?category" + "#respond" ;   });
```

Answer (score 0):

---

### [Demo JS Fiddle Diddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72vtW/)

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.comments-link a').attr('href', function (i, href) {
        return href.substring(0, href.indexOf('?category'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A link has some properties(hostname, protocol,pathname etc.), equal to the `location`-object, build the `href` based on these properties, e.g.:

```
$(".comments-link a")
  .attr("href", function() {  return [this.protocol,
                                      '//',
                                      this.hostname,
                                      '/',
                                      this.pathname,
                                      '?category'].join('') ;   });
```